# Ubuntu 18.04 how to move calendar indicator

Tags: gnome, 18.04, indicator, calendar

I have problem with ubuntu 18.04.
I installed extension [unite](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1287/unite/) and everything was ok, but the calendar indicator moved to the right side. Even if I deleted this extension, the calendar indicator stayes on the right side and my question is:
How to move calendar indicator to the center ?

Edit.
Problem solved.
I turned off all extensions and noticed that turning off those options fix the problem.

Unite: I turned off:  `Extend top left box`

Monitor: I turned off :`Move the clock`

Comment: Dissable all extensions temporarily using Gnome Tweaks and log out and back in. Does that help?

Comment: I set in system monitor  to move clock and in unite to expand top left box. Your advice was helpful. : )

Comment: If your problem is solved, then please write out an an answer in sufficient detail how you solved the issue for future users. it is perfectly fine on this site to answer your own question.